# Citeulike scientific articles search error

Tags: c++, linker, makefile

I'm trying to compile `ctr` from this search engine code: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chongw/citeulike/.

The code is there but I have the following error:

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `dir_exists (const char *) '
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried. Provided you installed libgsl, it should just compile (with a warning or two).

If you're missing `dir_exists` that tells me that `utils.cpp` is not being linked. You might check that, or in fact the output of

```
 make -Bsn
```

which *should* look similar to:

> `g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ main.cpp utils.cpp corpus.cpp ctr.cpp data.cpp opt.cpp -o ctr -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas`

Comment: Gracias, revisare tu sugerencia